# Applying image style to authors pictures in comments without preprocess function

Tags: users, comments, theming, media

Is there anyway I could apply an image style to the user picture in comments without using a preprocess function (YOURTHEME_preprocess_user_picture?)

The reason I ask this is because the preprocess function scales and crops the user pictures and I can no longer use the uncropped version (the original) in Views for example.

Any and all help on this is greatly appreciated.

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it through straight css, or look into a module that will allow you to customize image styles for different applications.

.comment .user-picture

.comment .user-picture img

Answer (score 0):

I found a module that will allow for applying styles to pictures in comments (and other pictures too, like avatars, node pictures, etc.) It did require a lot of tinkering for my site but it is working now. It can be found there: [Imagecache Profiles](https://drupal.org/project/imagecache_profiles)

Instructions can be found there: [How to use Imagecache Profiles](https://drupal.org/node/364511)